# VBA ClearContents if true

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Trying to clear the contents if the cell equals 100 *after* the email is sent to prevent additional emails going out. I'm not wishing to clear all the range. Only if it = 100.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("I36:I44"), 100) Then
        Call Mail_small_Text_Outlook
    Range("I36:I44").ClearContents
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you considered using a loop?

Comment: If I'm honest I haven't gotten the hang of loops yet.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a loop

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    Dim pos As Variant
    pos = Application.Match(100, Range("I36:I44"), 0)
    If IsNumeric(pos) Then
        Call Mail_small_Text_Outlook
        Range("I36:I44").Cells(pos).Value = ""
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: But `Match` will only match the first instance of 100, right? This assumes that there's only one instance of 100, which may or may not be the case. Also looping over 9 cells should be rather quick.

Comment: @BigBen I believe there will only be one instance (this is a continuation of an earlier question from the same OP)